# Modern way to read gamepad input in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, gamepad-api

**Question: I want to read gamepad/joystick input under c# and want to be able to tell which key is pressed. (at least few gamepad models)** 
Google and stackoverflow are full of different outdated solutions, most of them are asked in 2011. Some of the popular libraries, like **SharpDX** or **SlimDX** are already abandoned and not supported.

I end up using **SharpLibHid** that is messing with some raw input. And I even had some success. I am developing a WPF app, but that library requires WndProc from winforms, with help of this trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/42008211/3348804 everything works fine. The code is long and you can get great example software here: https://github.com/Slion/SharpLibHid

Point is I was able to extract this information from `SharpLib.Hid.Event`:

```
InputReport: 0000000F808080800000000000000000000000000202010200020002
DeviceInfo: ShanWan, USB WirelessGamepad 
[#Header# dwSize: 52, dwType: RIM_TYPEHID, hDevice: 65610, wParam: 1]
[#Hid# dwCount: 1, dwSizeHid: 28]
[#Keyboard# Message: 251658240, ExtraInformation: 2155905152, Flags: RI_KEY_MAKE, MakeCode: 28, VKey: 0, Reserved: 1]
[#Mouse# usButtonData: 0, usButtonFlags: RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN, lLastX: -2139062144, lLastY: 0, ulButtons: 1, ulExtraInformation: 0, usFlags: 28, ulRawButtons: 251658240]
[KeyId: 1835008, UsageCollection: 5]
UsageValues: [015][128][128][128][128][000][000][000][000][000][000][000][000][000][000][000][000][512][512][513][514]
UsageCollectionNameAndValue: GamePad (0x0005)
```

By using empirical approach I can observe some patterns and use some of these data to work with gamepad. It is simply not right way to do. And for another gamepad the `InputReport` patterd is totally different.

I saw alot of keymapper programs for gamepads - they can understand almost any device. So there is some way to do things right.

Maybe one can suggest atleast some documentation on how to work with gamepads or how to interpret raw data (**with real world examples**)?

Comment: You're on the right track, use WinMM, DirectInput or XInput.

Comment: i am using SharpDX and i havent problem...even in WIN10

Answer (score -1):

This is platform and framework dependent.

The only framework that fully supports this is UWP with the [GamePad API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamepad).

For .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET you need to rely on P/Invoke or custom implementation or 3rd party library. For WPF I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175304/reading-an-xbox-controller-in-a-wpf-application).

I needed to control a Raspberry Pi RC car with an XBox One S Controller. On Linux the files that correspond to game-pads (Joysticks) are `/dev/input/js[x]` where `x`  is a number (e.g. `/dev/input/js0`) ([docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/joydev/joystick-api.html)). This is considered legacy now and it is recommended to work with Linux `evdev` instead ([docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/input.html)).

There is a .NET Core [library](https://github.com/nahueltaibo/gamepad) on GitHub for game-pads on Linux. It continuously reads the `/dev/input/js0` file and raises events based on the data. It also consists of a working sample. Looking at the implementation will give you an idea of how to interpret raw data.